# What technique is to use for differentiation regarding $\delta$-functions?

Tags: calculus, analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Interesting differentiation regarding $\delta$-functions. Let we define a function $h(x)=e^{-ax}H(x)+e^{ax}H(-x)$ and we want to find the $n$-th derivative.
\begin{align}
h(x)&=e^{-ax}H(x)+e^{ax}H(-x)\\
h'(x)&=e^{-ax}\delta(x)-ae^{-ax}H(x)-e^{ax}\delta(x)+ae^{ax}H(-x)=ae^{ax}H(-x)-ae^{-ax}H(x)\\
\end{align}
I believe this step has no problem, but the following difference arises.
If we start from the resulting expression of the first derivative, then
\begin{align}
h''(x)&=(h'(x))'=-e^{ax}a\delta(x)+a^2e^{ax}H(-x)-e^{-ax}a\delta(x)+a^2e^{-ax}H(x)=a^2e^{ax}H(-x)+a^2e^{-ax}H(x)-(e^{-ax}+e^{ax})a\delta(x)
\end{align}
but if we start before we discard $(e^{-ax}-e^{ax})\delta(x)=0$ which has the derivative $-a(e^{-ax}+e^{ax})\delta(x)+(e^{-ax}-e^{ax})\delta'(x)$, then
\begin{align}
h''(x)&=-a(e^{-ax}+e^{ax})\delta(x)-e^{ax}a\delta(x)+a^2e^{ax}H(-x)-e^{-ax}a\delta(x)+a^2e^{-ax}H(x)=a^2e^{ax}H(-x)+a^2e^{-ax}H(x)-(e^{-ax}+e^{ax})a\delta(x)\\
&=a^2e^{ax}H(-x)+a^2e^{-ax}H(x)-2ae^{-ax}\delta(x).
\end{align}

Though the results are equal due to $\delta$'s property, but what are the strictly correct way to proceed further.

Could be any easier way to arrive at the $n$-derivatives?

Comment: I found some hints $\delta(x)f(x)=\delta(x)f(0)$ and $\delta'(x)f(x)=-\delta(x)f'(0)$ from here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803031.

Comment: There can be several strictly correct ways to proceed, but one might be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If $h$ is a distribution given by

$$h(x)=e^{-ax}H(x)+e^{ax}H(-x)$$

then the distributional derivative, $h'$, of $h$ is given by

$$h'(x)=\underbrace{e^{-ax}\delta(x)-e^{ax}\delta(x)}_{=0}+ae^{ax}H(-x)-ae^{-ax}H(x)\tag1$$

Now, if we differentiate the first two terms on the right-hand side of $(1)$ we  find that

$$\begin{align}
0&=(e^{-ax}\delta(x)-e^{ax}\delta(x))'\\\\
&=(-2\sinh(ax)\delta(x))'\\\\
&=-2\sinh(ax)\delta'(x)-2a\cosh(ax)\delta(x)\\\\
&=2a\cosh(ax)\delta(x)-2a\cosh(ax)\delta(x)\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Answer (score 1):

For an efficient way to calculate the $n$<sup>th</sup> derivative of $e^{-|x|}$ the identity given in the [post you found](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2803031/168433) can be used.

You first have $h^{(0)}(x)=h(x)=e^{-|x|}$ and $h^{(1)}(x)=h'(x)=\operatorname{sign}(x)e^{-|x|}.$ Then
$h''(x)-h(x)=-2\delta(x)$
gives $h^{(2)}(x) = h''(x) = h(x)-2\delta(x)=e^{-|x|}-2\delta(x)$ and also implies
$$
h^{(3)}(x)-h^{(1)}(x)=-2\delta'(x) \\
h^{(4)}(x)-h^{(2)}(x)=-2\delta''(x) \\
h^{(5)}(x)-h^{(3)}(x)=-2\delta'''(x) \\
\vdots
$$
From this we can conclude for example that
$$
h^{(5)}(x)
=h^{(3)}(x)-2\delta'''(x)
=\left( h^{(1)}(x) - 2\delta'(x) \right) - 2\delta'''(x)
= \operatorname{sign}(x)e^{-|x|} - 2\delta'(x) - 2\delta'''(x).
$$
Generally we find that
$$
h^{(n)}(x) = \begin{cases}
e^{-|x|} - 2\delta^{(n-2)}(x) - \cdots - 2\delta^{(0)}(x) & \text{if $n$ even} \\
\operatorname{sign}(x)e^{-|x|} - 2\delta^{(n-2)}(x) - \cdots - 2\delta^{(1)}(x) & \text{if $n$ odd} 
\end{cases}
$$